# PHP: platform independent shebang to put in top of PHP files to execute them with PHP CLI everywhere?

Tags: php, shell, command-line-interface, executable, shebang

If I have a .php script, I can run it from the terminal using

```
php myscript.php
```

In my case I'm mostly working on macOS and Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) but generally this works everywhere where PHP is installed.

However, I would prefer to make my .php script executable (i.e. `chmod u+x myscript.php`) so I can run it directly.

In order for this to work in any environment, I have to put a PHP shebang at the top of my script. Problem: the `php` binary has different locations on different platforms.

After searching around through similar stackexchange topics, the closest, most 'universal' way of doing this seems to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Is this correct, or what's the idea behind this? In what situations can this fail, and are there any fallbacks?

Comment: Yes, that's your best bet.

Comment: @RocketNuts : Of course, the `env` trick assumes that the correct `php` executable is in the PATH of the caller.